# Вывод массива структур (Си)

Tags: c, структуры

Написал программу, в которой задаются значения элементам массива структур, а затем весь массив выводится на экран. Массив представляет собой список интернет-тарифов с указанием цены, трафика, скорости и времени доступа. Вот только вывода не происходит. Не могу разобраться, в чём проблема.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


struct LIST
{
    char name[20];
    double cost;
    double speed;
    double traffic_volume;
    char time[20];
};


void list_init(struct LIST** list);
void print(struct LIST* list, int list_size);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("chcp 1251");
    struct LIST* list = (struct LIST*)malloc(4 * sizeof(struct LIST));
    int list_size = 4;
    list_init(&list);
    print(list, list_size);
    return 0;
}


void list_init(struct LIST** list)
{
    strcpy_s(list[0]->name, 20, "Light");
    list[0]->cost = 30;
    list[0]->speed = 2;
    list[0]->traffic_volume = 700;
    strcpy_s(list[0]->time, 20, "Неограничено");

    strcpy_s(list[1]->name, 20, "Fat");
    list[1]->cost = 38;
    list[1]->speed = 1.5;
    list[1]->traffic_volume = 1500;
    strcpy_s(list[1]->time, 20, "Неограничено");

    strcpy_s(list[2]->name, 20, "Fast");
    list[2]->cost = 45;
    list[2]->speed = 5;
    list[2]->traffic_volume = 700;
    strcpy_s(list[2]->time, 20, "Неограничено");

    strcpy_s(list[3]->name, 20, "Ultra");
    list[3]->cost = 80;
    list[3]->speed = 10;
    list[3]->traffic_volume = 1000;
    strcpy_s(list[3]->time, 20, "Неограничено");
}

void print(struct LIST* list, int list_size)
{
    printf("     Название тарифа\t Цена\tСкорость\tОбъём трафика\t    Время соединения\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%20s\t%5.3f\t%8.3f\t%13.3f\t20%s\n", list[i].name, list[i].cost, list[i].speed, list[i].traffic_volume, list[i].time);
    }
}
```

Comment: При выполнении `list[1]` происходит выход за пределы массива

Comment: Почему и что можно сделать?

Comment: `void list_init(struct LIST** list);` - > убрать одну звёздочку `void list_init(struct LIST* list);`

Comment: По идее, чтобы функция сохраняла изменения, нужно передавать указатель на указатель. Разве не так?

Comment: Указатель можно не менять. Память вы уже выделили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аргумент `struct LIST** list` указывает на массив указателей, а вы создали только **один** массив структур. И по-этому `list[1]->` использует несуществующий указатель, а ведь он у вас только один `struct LIST* list`.
Правильно надо передавать указатель на массив, а не на одну локальную переменную.

```c
  struct LIST * list = (struct LIST*)malloc(4 * sizeof(struct LIST));
  list_init ( list ) ;
//
//           ^^^ 
//                          vvv
// 
void list_init ( struct LIST * list ) {
  strcpy_s ( list [ 0 ] . name , 20 , "Light" ) ;
//
//                     ^^^
  ...
```

Comment: * на первый элемент массива указателей